# How to make a header/footer and content for print so that header/footer repeat at each page

Tags: html, css

I have a header div a footer and a content.
What I want to do is to print the page so that header and footer display on each page but content displays in between.
But the problem is content overlaps or hides under the header and footer.
Here's the Example of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/2ogx55p2/

I tried playing with contentDiv's margins and changing position to absolute or relative. but nothing worked out.

A help would be really nice. thanks

```css
.headerDiv {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  height: 100px;
}
.contentDiv {} .reportFooter {
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
@media print {
  .headerDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .contentDiv {
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .reportFooter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="headerDiv"></header>
<div class="contentDiv">
  <h1>1 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>2 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>3 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>4 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>5 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>6 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>7 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>8 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>9 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>12 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>13 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>14 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>15 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>16 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>17 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>18 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>19 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>20 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>21 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>22 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>23 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>24 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>25 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>26 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
</div>
<footer class="reportFooter"></footer>
```

Comment: If you add a fixed position to the header, the content cant see it any more and goes to the top. Try "top:100px" to let the content stay at its position

Comment: @Jonasw I already did that but in next pages it again overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

Do it parrent container as a flex.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
.headerDiv,
.contentDiv,
.reportFooter {
  width: 100%;
}
.headerDiv {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
.reportFooter {
  background-color: gray;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.headerDiv,
.reportFooter {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
.contentDiv {
  flex: 1000 0;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

```html
<header class="headerDiv"></header>
<div class="contentDiv">
  <h1>1 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>2 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>3 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>4 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>5 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>6 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>7 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>8 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>9 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>12 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>13 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>14 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>15 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>16 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>17 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>18 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>19 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>20 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>21 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>22 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>23 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>24 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>25 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
  <h1>26 test Test TEst TESt TEST</h1>
</div>
<footer class="reportFooter"></footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, but using this CSS he footer only shows on last page but not on both pages

Comment: I think this can't be done on css. U can try insert block with css page-break-before: always; for next page, but this is not automatical.